# Visual Studio + Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, gitlab

for some unknown reason, I must close my vs2019 if I want to git add ., if I try to do so when my IDE is open, I can't, it says permission denied.
error: open("BankSystem/.vs/BankSystem/v16/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'BankSystem/.vs/BankSystem/v16/Browse.VC.opendb'
fatal: adding files failed

Comment: What does this have to do with GitLab?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to reinstall your visual studio code

Comment: The question doesn't even mention Visual Studio Code. ;)